# similarity : $z'=(1-i)z+1+i$ with the curve of $e^x-1-x$.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Let $S$ be the similarity defined by : $S(z)=(1-i)z+1+i$, for a complex number $z$ in the complex plane.

What is the image of the curve : $y=e^x-x-1$ by the similarity $S$.

---

My work : Let $z=x+iy$ and $S(z)=a+ib$, where $x,y$ are real numbers. So we can write : $$ \begin{cases} a=x+y+1 \\ b=y-x+1.\end{cases}$$ Solving the first one for $a$ we get : $ \ln a=x$, plug this in the second equation to get :$b=a-2\ln a.$

Hence the image of the given curve is the curve : $y=x-2\ln x.$

I'm I correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be correct to me. You managed to write it down in such a way that it can be confusing, though, and there will certainly be moments when you confuse yourself, if you keep writing like this.

I'd suggest the following:

- try not so much to consider the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ to really be the same thing. If you switch between the two like you did in this exercise, confusion is bound to arise.
- there are different $x$'s and $y$'s in your post. The original $x$ and $y$ just express the real coordinates $(x,y)$ of a complex number. You then show that the image of the curve under $S$ gives coordinates $(a,b)$ satisfying $b = a-2\ln(a)$. You then call these coordinates $x$ and $y$ again, despite being different from the previous $x$ and $y$.